# Running programs depending on java not working

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, bioinformatics

I have several programs running on Java that suddenly stopped working. 
I ran the commands to start them at command line and nothing happens. When I ran: `$java -version` nothing happens either.

If a I run: `whereis java` the output is:

```
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

And if I ran `wheris {the program depending on java}`, I get a similar output. For example, for fastqc software:

```
$whereis fastqc
fastqc: /usr/bin/fastqc /usr/bin/X11/fastqc /usr/share/fastqc /usr/share/man/man1/fastqc.1.gz
```

I have no idea what to do. Besides, I checked if java is properly installed by:

```
apt-get install default-jre
```

And the output was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ifeffit libbit-vector-perl libcarp-clan-perl libchemistry-elements-perl
  libchemistry-formula-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdate-calc-perl
  libdate-calc-xs-perl libdate-manip-perl libifeffit-perl libio-stringy-perl
  libmath-combinatorics-perl libmath-derivative-perl libmath-round-perl
  libmath-spline-perl libntdb1 libole-storage-lite-perl
  libparse-recdescent-perl libreadonly-perl libreadonly-xs-perl
  libregexp-common-perl libspreadsheet-writeexcel-perl
  libstatistics-descriptive-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtext-english-perl
  libtext-glob-perl libtie-ixhash-perl libtime-stopwatch-perl
  libtk-filedialog-perl libtk-gbarr-perl libtk-histentry-perl libtk-pod-perl
  libtk-splashscreen-perl libwwwbrowser-perl libxray-absorption-perl
  libxray-scattering-perl linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic perlindex pgplot5 python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

I also made update, remove and re-install; but nothing changes.

If you have any suggestions please... I am obviously NOT an advanced-informatician...so I do not know what to do.
Thanks!

Comment: explain "nothing happens"... does it mean the prompt hangs, or it exits with no entry?

Comment: They **stopped** working - so they were in the past. What did you change before they stopped working? Did you install another jre? An application? Anything?

Comment: Hi, 'nothing happens' means it exits with no entry, thanks.

Comment: Of course sth changed after it was working. The problem is that I made different things ... Update, install and restart. The virtual machine I worked with, also gave me an error, and system problem detected. This error was fixed, but java is not working still :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to restart? Usually a nice go to as a first pass at debugging.

Did you not accidentally rewrite your `$PATH`? i.e. java is still installed, but not in your default path anymore. So running `java --version` will also fail.

You could also try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` to install the development kit for java. This also contains `jre` so might fix things. But my first quess would be your `$PATH` is broken.

Comment: I've also tried to install the developer package you mentiond with no succeed either...
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ifeffit libbit-vector-perl libcarp-clan-perl libchemistry-elements-perl

Comment: libchemistry-formula-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdate-calc-perl
  libdate-calc-xs-perl libdate-manip-perl libifeffit-perl libio-stringy-perl

Comment: libmath-combinatorics-perl libmath-derivative-perl libmath-round-perl
  libmath-spline-perl libntdb1 libole-storage-lite-perl
  libparse-recdescent-perl libreadonly-perl libreadonly-xs-perl
  libregexp-common-perl libspreadsheet-writeexcel-perl
  libstatistics-descriptive-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtext-english-perl
  libtext-glob-perl libtie-ixhash-perl libtime-stopwatch-perl
  libtk-filedialog-perl libtk-gbarr-perl libtk-histentry-perl libtk-pod-perl
  libtk-splashscreen-perl libwwwbrowser-perl libxray-absorption-perl

Comment: libxray-scattering-perl linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic perlindex pgplot5 python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-source visualvmThe following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-7-jdk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 16,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 20,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: Get:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [16,1 MB]
Fetched 16,1 MB in 15s (1.016 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-7-jdk:amd64.
(Reading database ... 308068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jdk_7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
~# java --version
And nothing exits...

Comment: How can I fix my PATH then?

Comment: try PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games". See http://askubuntu.com/questions/386629/what-are-the-default-path-values for details. This is the default Ubuntu Desktop path

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the problem was the two versions of java that I have installed. The programs I was trying to run needed an older version of java, and when I installed the newer it has been set to use it as default. I finally solved this out, changing the default version of jave to use:

update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

### Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

- 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1074      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1074      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

And that's it!
:)